# How to classify texts that are related to the bible based on their content

Tags: machine-learning, text, nlp, classification, text-classification

I have a database of texts from comments of social networks (FB,Twitter).
My goal is to classify texts that have strong relation to the bible based on their content (for example if there are cites or "biblical" words that are used.
This is a binary classification problem and i need help to figure out how to approach it (maybe use the bible as a dictionary somehow). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can train a supervised binary classifier (e.g. a logistic regression over TF-IDF counters, or a fasttext classifier, or fine-tune a BertForSequenceClassification).

Then apply this classifier to your database of comments and find a reasonable value of the probability threshold to keep only the comments in which the classifier is confident enough.

As positive examples for training, you can use the sentences from the Bible itself, sentences for Bible-related Wikipedia articles, etc. As negative samples, you can use any corpus of sentences collected from web - e.g. one of [the Leipzig corpora](https://wortschatz.uni-leipzig.de/en/download/).

Comment: Thanks! the idea of training a classifier on other texts for training and than testing on my dataset sounds great. do you have maybe references for python or r notebooks of similar codes?

Comment: just google for "tf-idf + logistic regression"; this is for example the first search result https://www.kaggle.com/sudhirnl7/logistic-regression-tfidf